# Docker command not found while docker.service is Active (running)

Tags: linux, docker, centos7

I've installed docker on CentOS 7, but when I run docker, I get `bash: docker: command not found...`

Other apps that require docker gave this error: `"docker": executable file not found in $PATH`

which docker returns: `no docker in (/usr/.....`

whereis docker returns: `docker: /etc/docker /usr/libexec/docker /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz`

This is how I installed it:

```
yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2

yum-config-manager --add-repo \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

sudo yum update -y && sudo yum install -y \
  containerd.io-1.2.13 \
  docker-ce-19.03.11 \
  docker-ce-cli-19.03.11

mkdir /etc/docker

cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOF
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "storage-opts": [
    "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
  ]
}
EOF

sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read the official documentation at [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/).

---

#### Did you successfully meet the OS requirements?

- To install Docker Engine you need a maintained version of CentOS 7,
  archived versions are not supported or tested.
- The centos-extras repository must be activated. This repository is
  activated by default, but if you deactivated it, you have to activate
  it again.
- The Overlay2 storage driver is recommended.

#### Have you deleted the older versions?

- Older versions of Docker were called `docker` or `docker-engine`.  If
  these are installed, uninstall them, along with associated
  dependencies.

  ```
  $ sudo yum remove docker \
                     docker-client \
                     docker-client-latest \
                     docker-common \
                     docker-latest \
                     docker-latest-logrotate \
                     docker-logrotate \
                     docker-engine
  ```

---

I have sent you some document texts from the [official Docker documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/), I would recommend you to read the whole [document page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/).